# Formtastic translation missing: en.formtastic.submit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

```
<%= semantic_form_for :index, :method => "post" do |f| %>
```

<% f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.autocompleted_input :category_post, :url =>  home_autocomplete_category_name_path %>
    <%= f.autocompleted_input :place_post, :url => home_autocomplete_town_name_path %>
    <%= f.buttons %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

Gives me this error:

```
<input class="submit" id="index_submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="translation missing: en.formtastic.submit">
```

Any ideas? I thought it did not rely on the yml file and had default values elsewhere, if not do I have to add values to en.yml and if so how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so anyone wondering about this in the future wonder how to solve it, simply go into the en.yml file and put the value in under the route desribed so this example simply needed:

```
en:
  formtastic:
    submit: "search"
```